# How to remove Genymotion from Android Studio and uninstall it from Windows?

Tags: windows, android-studio, uninstallation, genymotion

I'd like to know how to uninstall Genymotion from Android Studio and Windows?

My Android Studio version is 1.0.1
My operating system is Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I will provide you a short and fancy answer from Genymotion official documentation

**To properly uninstall Genymotion, follow the procedure:**

- **Remove all virtual devices** using trash button in Genymotion.
- Open Control Panel > Programs and Features. **Right-click on the Genymotion application and select Uninstall**.
- Follow the uninstallation steps.
- **Delete the
  directory** C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Genymobile. *(You can click Windows+R and type %appdata% to jump into AppData folder quickly)*
- Run **regedit** and
  delete the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Genymobile. *(Same using Windows+R combination)*
- To remove all
  programs used by Genymotion, you may also **uninstall the VirtualBox**
  application from Control Panel > Programs and Features.

[Check this source on official Genymotion website](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#genymotion-uninstall)